# Using preventDefault in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

The validation is working correctly, however when the user fails the validation the default action is still carried out. So validation fails and the joke is still returned. If validation fails, the Joke should not be returned. I have tried to use preventDefault but no luck.

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";



function Search() {

    const [joke, setJoke] = useState()
    const [firstname, setFN] = useState("sharoze")
    const [lastname, setLN] = useState("khan")

    const newJoke = (first, last) => {
        fetch(`http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random?firstName=${first}&lastName=${last}`)
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(result2 => {
                console.log(result2)
                setJoke(result2.value.joke)

            })

    }


    function validateForm() {
        var firstname = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value;
        var lastname = document.getElementsByName("lastname")[0].value;
        if (firstname === "" && lastname === "") {
            alert("Please enter atleast one name");

        }
        else if (!(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(firstname + lastname))) {
            alert("'Only alphabets allowed'");

        }

    }


    return (
        <div className="jokeForm" >
            <form name="searchForm" >
                <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" value={firstname} onChange={(e) => setFN(e.target.value)} />
                <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" value={lastname} onChange={(e) => setLN(e.target.value)} />
            </form>
            <button id="button" onClick={(e) => { validateForm(newJoke(firstname, lastname)); return false; }}>click here for a personalised chuckle</button>
            <h3>{joke}</h3>
        </div >


    )
}




export default Search;
```

sorry the  code has been a little butchered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem I can see is that you don't pass `event` argument from `onClick` to your validation function, hence `preventDefault()` function is not working. 
Try to pass `event` argument to validation function and then use this argument in function to apply `preventDefault()`.

--Update--

You don't need to use `preventDefault()` at all. Just modify your validation function to call new joke only if validation is passed.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";



function Search() {

    const [joke, setJoke] = useState()
    const [firstname, setFN] = useState("sharoze")
    const [lastname, setLN] = useState("khan")

    const newJoke = (first, last) => {
        fetch(`http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random?firstName=${first}&lastName=${last}`)
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(result2 => {
                console.log(result2)
                setJoke(result2.value.joke)

            })

    }


    function validateForm() {
        var firstname = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value;
        var lastname = document.getElementsByName("lastname")[0].value;
        if (firstname === "" && lastname === "") {
            alert("Please enter atleast one name");
            return false;
        }
        else if (!(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(firstname + lastname))) {
            alert("'Only alphabets allowed'");
            return false;
        }
        newJoke(firstname, lastname);
    }


    return (
        <div className="jokeForm" >
            <form name="searchForm" >
                <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" value={firstname} onChange={(e) => setFN(e.target.value)} />
                <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" value={lastname} onChange={(e) => setLN(e.target.value)} />
            </form>
            <button id="button" onClick={() => validateForm()}>click here for a personalised chuckle</button>
            <h3>{joke}</h3>
        </div >


    )
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code above to the full script, sorry about that. The search function is what returns the joke so do I need to add in preventDefault into that?

Comment: Hi. You have to add `e` argument to `validateForm` function in your Class component and also pass `e` as an argument when calling in your button `onClick.`

Comment: @SharozeKhan I've modified your code. Please check if works now.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help! unfortunately it is still not working, the joke still gets returned.

Comment: I am not sure if the prevent default needs to be in the search function as that is what returns the joke, but when I place it there I start to get errors. So I am not sure what the issue is as the validation is working correctly but the preventDefault seems to have no affect.

Comment: @SharozeKhan sure, then you don't need `preventDefault` at all. You should edit your `validateForm` function. If any of validation rule is not passed then `return false` in `if` block. If everything is ok - then call for a new joke or return joke - as you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203408/discussion-between-serhii-zharkov-and-sharoze-khan).